# Python - Combinig pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 dataframes that I'd like to combine. They look like this:

```
df1       |df2        |df3
col1 col2 |col1 col2  |col1 col3
1    5     2    9      1    some
                       2    data
```

I'd like the first two df-s to be merged into the third df based on `col1`, so the desired output is

```
df3
col1 col3 col2
1    some 5
2    data 9
```

How can I achieve this? I'm trying:

```
df3['col2'] = df1[df1.col1 == df3.col1].col2 if df1[df1.col1 == df3.col1].col2 is not None else df2[df2.col1 == df3.col1].col2
```

For this I get `ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare`

It is guaranteed, that `df3`'s `col1` values are present either in `df1` or `df2`. What's the way to do this? PLEASE NOTE, that a simple `concat` will not work, since there is other data in `df3`, not just `col1`.

Comment: IIUC you can do `df3.merge(df1, on='col1', how='outer').merge(df2, on='col1', how='outer')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `df1` and `df2` don't have duplicates in `col1`, you can try this:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2]).merge(df3)
```

[image]

---

*Data*:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1], 'col2': [5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [2], 'col2': [9]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2], 'col3': ['some', 'data']})
```